# How can I accumulate R-squared over time intervals with a model that makes predictions for a single interval?

Tags: regression, time-series, r-squared

I have a model that makes a prediction of the change in a number during a time interval. The model depends on covariates that happen during the interval of prediction, as well as a weighted average of those same covariates during recent past intervals. There is a lot of noise in this process.

$y_t = f(x_t) + g(x_{t-1},x_{t-2},...) + \epsilon_t$

I want to use the model to estimate the expected evolution of $y$ given some expected values of $x_t$.

There is a question about the appropriate size of the interval with which data is sampled. As I expected, using larger interval sizes almost always results in a larger $R^2$. This is intuitive to me because noise scales with the square root of time.

Taken to the extreme, I might naively conclude that I should make the interval size cover the entire process, which would effectively mean that $g()$ drops out of the model, since there are no previous periods anymore. But I have good theoretical and empirical reasons to believe that $g()$ is an important part of the process.

How can I go about choosing an optimal interval size in this case? My hope is that there is some way to scale the $R^2$ based on the interval size, analogous to how the mean of a process scales linearly with $t$ but the standard deviation scales with $\sqrt{t}$.

To ask this question in another way: given the model specification above for $y_t$ and it's associated $R^2$, you can derive a model for $y_t + y_{t+1}$, but can you derive the $R^2$ for this new model?

**EXAMPLE**: if you understand the above, no need to look at the below. This is some code that simulates a simple process with the features described above. It then fits a model directly on the output, and another on some downsampled output. The second model has a higher $R^2$ even though it is the wrong model. I know it is wrong because I simulated the data and fit the first model in a way that matches the true data generating process. The reason the send model has a higher $R^2$ is because the noise "cancels itself out a bit" over the longer interval length.

```
rm(list = ls())

library(conflicted)
library(tidyverse)
library(foreach)
conflict_prefer_all("purrr", "foreach")
set.seed(123)

n_runs <- 40
run_length <- 50
x_prob_threshold <- 0.9
look_back_length <- 10
f_coef <- 20
g_coef <- 10

pad_result <- function(x){c(x, rep(0, look_back_length))} # guarentee runs do not have overlapping x vals

do_single_run <- function() {
  x_probs <- runif(run_length)
  x_vals <- rnorm(run_length)
  accumulate2(x_vals, x_probs, \(prev, x_val, x_prob){
    if (prev == 0) {
      if (x_prob > x_prob_threshold) {
        x_val
      } else {
        0
      }
    } else {
      if (x_prob > x_prob_threshold) {
        0
      } else {
        x_val
      }
    }
  }, .init = 0) |> pad_result()
}

epsilon_sd <- 50

x <- foreach(run = 1:n_runs, .combine = c) %do% do_single_run()

accumulate_x = function(x, n){
  imap_dbl(x, \(x_, i){
    if (i <= n) {
      index <- 1:(i - 1)
      sum(x[index])
    } else {
      sum(x[(i - n):(i - 1)])
    }
  })
}

cum_x <- accumulate_x(x, look_back_length)
y <- f_coef * x + g_coef * cum_x + rnorm(length(x), sd = epsilon_sd)
m <- lm(y ~ x + cum_x - 1)
message("correct model results")
summary(m) |> print()

downsample <- function(x){
  n = length(x)
  if (n%%2 == 1) {
    stop("cannot downsample an odd size")
  }
  1:(n/2) |> sapply(\(i){x[i*2-1] + x[i*2]})
}

x_ <- downsample(x)
cum_x_ <- accumulate_x(x_, look_back_length/2)
y_ <- downsample(y)

m_ <- lm(y_ ~ x_ + cum_x_ - 1)
message("incorrect model results")
summary(m_) |> print()
```

Output:

```
correct model results

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + cum_x - 1)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-159.64  -32.78   -0.76   31.54  172.30 

Coefficients:
      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
x       21.637      1.561   13.87   <2e-16 ***
cum_x   10.338      0.526   19.66   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 49.31 on 2438 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.187, Adjusted R-squared:  0.1864 
F-statistic: 280.5 on 2 and 2438 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

incorrect model results

Call:
lm(formula = y_ ~ x_ + cum_x_ - 1)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-217.763  -45.599   -0.129   42.060  216.499 

Coefficients:
       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
x_       25.510      2.217   11.51   <2e-16 ***
cum_x_   19.684      1.042   18.90   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 68.76 on 1218 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.2801,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.279 
F-statistic:   237 on 2 and 1218 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my not very formal attempt at an answer

$R^2$ = $\frac{explained\_variance}{total\_variance}=\frac{explained\_variance}{explained\_variance + residual\_variance}$, abbreviated to $\frac{e}{e+d}$

I claim, in a very hand wavey way, that $\sqrt{e}$ scales like an expected value with time (proprtional to $t$), and $\sqrt{d}$ scales like a standard devaition with time (proprtional to $\sqrt{t}$)

let $r_1$ be the $R^2$ for model $m_1$ in the simulation. If we want to estimate $R^2$ for model $m_2$ which is just fit on data downsampled by a factor of 2, we plug in the numbers:

Without loss of generality set $e = r_1$ and $d = 1$

$r_2=\frac{(2\sqrt{r_1})^2}{2\sqrt{r_1})^2 + \sqrt(2)}=\frac{4r_1}{4r_1+2}$

In the above simulation, $r_1 = 0.187$ and $r_2=0.2801$ If I estimate $r_2$ using the above method I get $0.2722411$ which is close to the true number. Coincedence? Not sure yet but I a, leaning toward no.

Comment: I should add that this answer is not acceptable. Even if it is approximately correct, it doesn't allow me to choose the correct model based on some goodness of fit measure. This method seems to show that $m_1$ is a slightly worse model than $m_2$ which is known to be incorrect by construction.

Answer (score 0):

A better answer is to just roll up the high frequency estimate to the same frequency as the other estimate and manually calculate the $R^2$.

```
expected_y2_from_m = m$fitted.values |> downsample()
expected_y2_from_m2 = m2$fitted.values

getR2 = function(exp_y, act_y){
  mu = mean(act_y)
  sum((exp_y - mu)^2)/sum((act_y - mu)^2)
}

getR2(expected_y2_from_m2, y2)
getR2(expected_y2_from_m, y2)
```

this method correctly identifies the best model

```
> getR2(expected_y2_from_m2, y2)
[1] 0.2891062
> getR2(expected_y2_from_m, y2)
[1] 0.2991645
```

Comment: I will accept this answer when the self acceptance timer runs out